# Installing font package in TexShop

Tags: packages, installing, texshop, installing-fonts

I am encountering some difficulty using a specific font.  I would like to use the font [*AlfaSlabOne*](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/alfaslabone), however I am running into two problems:

**Problem #1**: When I click the "download" button on CTAN, nothing appears to happen.  The file does not appear in my "downloads" folder, and it is as if an attempt was not even made to download the file.

**Problem #2**: Assuming I am able to download the alfaslabone.sty file, I do not understand what I should do with it. I realize there have been several posts covering this topic, but they often use terminology or concepts that I do not understand and so I have not been able to follow these tutorials.

My (meager) progress at addressing Problem #2 is currently as follows: I have found a "Library" folder under "Macintosh HD".  I then select a "TeX" folder, but then I am confronted with a "Distributions", "Documentation", "Local", "Root" and "texbin" folders, and I have no idea what any of these mean or how I should use them.

Comment: As Murray mentions it is already in mactex. So if would help us if you can explain **exactly** what you have installed. For example which version of mactex or what ever larex you installed (it is listed at the top of the log file)

Comment: Don’t touch that TeX folder in that Library folder. It appears that you have either BasicTeX or the full MacTeX installed. Do you have the TeX Live Utility application in a TeX folder inside you Applcations folder?

Comment: @daleif: The following line is at the top of my log file: _This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.5.23)_.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: I do have the TeX Utility application in my TeX folder.

Comment: Then you're hopelessly behind. I think that package came in 2020/21. Install mactex 2021

Comment: @daleif I would not necessarily disagree that I am hopelessly behind!  Per your instructions, I have installed mactex 2021...I will see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TeXShop, did you install it as part of MacTeX? If so, then the AlfaSlabOne font and supporting style file should already be installed.

To use the font as your document's text font, simply put the following in your preamble:

```
 \usepackage{alfaslabone}
```

Comment: I do not know if I installed TeXShop with MacTex.  However, when I include \usepackage{alfaslabone} in my preamble and try to compile, I get the error message: File `alfaslabone.sty' not found.

Comment: @Sam: What TeX Distribution did you install? The Library folder at the base of your hard drive is wrong for installing packages.